# Video encoded by Expression Encoder is 3 seconds long on YouTube

Tags: encoding, youtube, expression-encoder

I am trying to upload video created using MS Expression Encoder 4 to YouTube, but after processing any video is played in 3 seconds.

Any ideas? Is it problem of encoder configuration or YouTube?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running into the same issue when I encoded a video using the Expression Encoder SDK and uploading the videos to YouTube. I didn't experience the issue when I used the BaselineH264VideoProfile video profile. I also think the one that outputs WMV didn't experience the issue as well. Not sure if this will help you, but if not hopefully someone else.

Thanks,
James

Comment: Hi James,

thank you for your answer. Meanwhile I was able to upload WMV.

Dusan

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I've experience similar 'short video' issues with EE 4. I noticed that 5 miniute vidoes were actually only 15 seconds or so long. Doesn't happen all the time; about 20%. After turning disabling audio profile, the problem went away. Experimenting just a bit more I found I could reliably repoduce this issue by rapidly changing audio volume while screen capturing... No idea why but the capture definitely freezes